What is the origin of the quote "Educated individuals are good for all of society."
In this video by Babylon Bee (at 1:16), the lady claims that either Che Guevara or Karl Marx said something along the lines of "Educated individuals are good for all of society.". Is that true? I cannot find it. And, if it's a true quote, what kind of education did it refer to?
As far as I can see via a quick search, Karl Marx basically said nothing about education.

They might have confused them with Lenin or Stalin, who have a lot of quotes around the theme of education. Literacy was a big problem for the early USSR. However, I cannot find an exact matching quote there either. It's possible that it was paraphrased.

The Babylon Bee is a satirical news site. It's comedy, so it's not a serious attribution.

@SPavel You won't find a source. "populace" and "all of society" are terminologies Marxists would never use without a clear reference to the classless society of an (utopian) future. In reference to real, existing societies, to their thinking no action ever benefits "the whole", but only certain classes/groups.

@ccprog Orthodox Marxists, no. Lenin and Stalin? Absolutely.

This is a comedy sketch about student debt relief. The exact quote in the video is:

"An educated populace is good for all of society." Karl Guevara or
Che Marx said that!

This line is clearly meant to imply that university graduates are miseducated and indoctrinated. There is absolutely no reason to think this quote might be attributed to either of them.
Ironically, Karl Marx took a completely opposite position to the one being associated with him here. In Critique of the Gotha Program he wrote that public funding for higher education "only means in fact defraying the cost of education of the upper classes from the general tax receipts."
Che Guevara, Lenin and other famous Communist figures did write more extensively about education, but I see no reason to try and mine their works for the origin of this cliche.

Moreover, the Babylon Bee is a satirical news site. It's comedy, so it's not a serious attribution.

@cmw Correct. hence my first sentence.

Agreed, just adding to it. It's not just comedy, all of the Babylon Bee is satirical. It would be strange to take anything they said seriously! You're right in not even bothering to look it up, since it's not actually claiming one of those figure said such a thing.

In fact, Babylon Bee has gotten in trouble multiple different times in various venues online due to people taking the content of their articles seriously. They've had posts removed and even got a "False" Snopes report once. Compared to other such satirical sites, it appears they have problems marking their content as satirical, problems telling the difference between satire and genuine bullying, and their audience has problems recognizing satire as such (which is perhaps understandable if they originally came for the bullying).
